# Euler Lagrange Equation of Ricci functional

Tags: differential-geometry, riemannian-geometry, calculus-of-variations, general-relativity

Let $\left(M^n, g\right)$ be an $n$ dimensional closed manifold, $T$ a tensor on this manifold, we define the energy functional to be
$$
\mathcal{F}_T=\int_M|T|^2 d vol(g).
$$
Let $g$ be a family of metrics defined as $g=g_0+t h$, where $h$ is a symmetric 2 tensor. The gradient of this energy functional will be denoted by grad $\mathcal{F}_T$ and defined as
$$
\frac{\partial}{\partial t} \mathcal{F}_T=\int_M\left\langle\operatorname{grad} \mathcal{F}_T, h\right\rangle d \ vol(g).
$$

Now, we want to compute the gradient of the following functional:
$$
\mathcal{F}_{\text {Ric }}=\int_M|R i c|^2 d \ vol(g).
$$

We want to show that the gradient of the above functional is the following:

$$
\operatorname{gradF}_{\text {Ric }}=-\Delta R_{i j}-\frac{1}{2} \Delta R g_{i j}+\nabla_i \nabla_j R-2 R^{p q} R_{i p j q}+\frac{1}{2}|R i c|^2 g_{i j}.
$$

I have computed the variation of the Ricci tensor, metric tensor, and volume element. Could you help me understand the following computation? How to show the equality of (1)?

$$
\begin{aligned}
\frac{\partial}{\partial t} \int_M|R i c|^2 d \mu=& \int_M\left\langle R_{i j}, \frac{\partial}{\partial t} R_{i j}\right\rangle d \mu+\int_M\left\langle\frac{1}{2}|R i c|^2 g_{i j}-2 R_{i p} R_j^p, h_{i j}\right\rangle dvol(g) .......          (1)  \\
=& \int_M\left\langle R_{i j},-\Delta h_{i j}\right\rangle d vol(g) +\int_M\left\langle R_{i j},-\nabla_i \nabla_j T r_g(h)\right\rangle dvol(g) \\
&+\int_M\left\langle R_{i j}, \nabla^p \nabla_i h_{j p}\right\rangle dvol(g)+\int_M\left\langle R_{i j}, \nabla^p \nabla_j h_{i p}\right\rangle dvol(g) \\
&+\frac{1}{2} \int_M\left\langle|\operatorname{Ric}|^2 g_{i j}, h_{i j}\right\rangle dvol(g)
\end{aligned}
$$
Finally, how can I proceed from here? Somehow I can use the divergence theorem? Thanks so much.

Edit: I think I got an answer (not precise though). At the very end of the calculation, he uses the fact that the divergence and gradient are "dual" to each other.

Comment: To compute $(1)$: $dvol(g)$ depends on $g$, so
$\partial_t \int_M F(g) dvol(g) = \int_M \partial_t(F(g)) dvol(g) + \int_M F(g)\partial_t dvol(g)$. Exact formulation can be found [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_formulas_in_Riemannian_geometry#Variation_formulas)